# add forms authentication to mvc4 site created with empty template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Mvc4 site that was created eith the empty template. How can I now include forms authentication to the site?

I have checked a few  books and shearched but i have not come up with any relevant information.

my webconfig looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>

    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
      <connectionStrings>
//
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Are you going to use existing membership providers or use a custom way to authenticate your users?

Comment: @BartBeyers I am going to use custom authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Web.config file in your project, check if the mode type for authentication is "Forms". See below:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="20" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

The mode type for authentication have 4 defferent types, like below:

- Windows
- Forms
- Passport
- None

If you don't see `<authentication>` element in the Web.config file, add it inside the `<system.web>` element. Also because you're using empty templates, you need to add some logic for your Form based authentication. Like create `Account Controller` and `Login Action`.

Comment: I included my webconfig, I dont see the authentication mode entry

Comment: If you don't see it, you can add it inside <system.web> element.